# Nav bar's right button is missing

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a custom button for the navigation bar's right button. But it is always missing. This is my code which was called from `viewWillAppear:`:

```
func setNavBar() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

    let rightNavButton : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "photo_camera"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onCameraButton(sender:)))

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesBackButton = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = rightNavButton

}
```

The back button is shown so `topItem` is definitely not nil. Yet I don't know why but the right bar button is missing. I've tried making it an array with only a single item, but it still didn't work. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

EDIT: BTW, the view controller that has this code is called from another one that has a pretty similar code and it works perfectly. Dunno what's the difference between those two. Here's the working code:

```
func setNavBar() {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

    let rightNavButtons : [UIBarButtonItem] = [
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "edit"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onEditButton)),
        UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "settings"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(onSettingsButton))

    ]

    self.parent?.title = "Profile"
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesBackButton = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItems = rightNavButtons
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented following code in my current project to add right bar button.

```
func addRightButton(title: String) {
    let barRightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonTapped(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barRightButton
}
```

This is working fine for me in my whole project. you should need to use `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` instead of `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.setRightBarButton(rightNavButton, animated: false)`

Try this and let me know if it is working. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Huh. That's weird. Your code did actually work. However, if you take a look at the second `setNavBar` code in the EDIT section, when I tried to get rid of the navigationController, that one didn't show any buttons when it was working before. Anyway, I'll consider this the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add right bar button item using following method:-

```
func configureRightBarButton(title: String, icon: UIImage?, withColor: UIColor?, withTarget: AnyObject) {
        // create back button
        let btnRightMenu: UIButton = UIButton()
        btnRightMenu.tintColor = withColor
        if var image = icon {
            image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            btnRightMenu.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
        btnRightMenu.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        btnRightMenu.setTitleColor(withColor, for: .normal)
        btnRightMenu.sizeToFit()
        btnRightMenu.addTarget(withTarget, action: #selector (rightBarButtonClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnRightMenu)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the accepted answer is enough and simpler for me.